How does Symfony Scheduler component get triggered?
With the Symfony Scheduler component we can schedule actions that get executed at predetermined times. So, the component works as a dispatcher of tasks that live inside the Symfony world.
But I can't find any obvious documentation of how this ties in to the operating system. I would expect that an entry is added to the system crontab, so that it triggers the Scheduler component engine, so that it can then trigger the tasks it is set up to execute.
Is that how it works? Or is it a system service? Or is it something else?

Symfony Schedule works on top of Symfony Messenger, it's not tied to the OS in any way. It generates and dispatches messages to be consumed whenever the Scheduler trigger is met.
The only "tie" to the OS system is the execution of the Symfony Messenger consumer, which is done however you want it to be done.
To consume the Scheduler messages, you run the Messenger consumer, specifying the Scheduler transport. It goes like this (assuming you haven't named your scheduler otherwise in the attribute, e.g. #[AsSchedule('important')]):
php bin/console messenger:consume scheduler_default

It's mentioned in the docs here.
Besides the docs, these articles might be helpful:

Symfony Scheduler — How it Really Works
Symfony 7: Upgrading and What's new - New Component: Scheduler


I think that's confusing you is the need that Scheduler actually meets. I believe Scheduler is mostly useful in "serverless" scenarios, where you do not have a server where you can schedule commands to be executed at arbitrary intervals. If the only thing you have is a running process, then suddenly Scheduler looks much more interesting.

Thanks a lot for your answer. But then my question is transferred to Symfony Messenger. How does it run? I know how Symfony gets started from bin/console, and from web requests; but in these cases it's just a calendar event that starts Symfony? "It's Friday, I should run now"? What is the mechanism under that? When I boot up my Ubuntu, messenger:consume is not running yet, how is it started? Thanks!

The consumer is executed with the command above. It's running when you run it. Again: it's not tied to the OS in any way, as already mentioned above. Once executed, it keeps running in a loop, and consuming available messages. In the case of Scheduler, it automatically dispatches new messages when the scheduler trigger is met.

Ok, so it's just a matter of saying the obvious, that I should put php bin/console messenger:consume scheduler_default in my system crontab if I want it to actually do anything? If this is a critical part of the installation/configuration, why is nobody saying it out loud? I am sorry if my questions are dumb, I'm still trying to get this into my weary head... thanks for your patience and prompt replies.

If you need the consumer to run, you should put it somewhere so it's executed, yes. You can put it your crontab, if the system you are using has a crontab, and executing it regularly seems reasonable. Although frankly, if you already control your scheduled commands with crontab, maybe you do not use Scheduler at all? I believe this is a more useful component for other situations where you do not have a crontab. Think serverless.

@pgr https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#consuming-messages-running-the-worker contains all details about how to run Messenger's workers and how to deploy it to production

Thanks, things are starting to make more sense to me now. I have reasons to prefer Scheduler to cron even in systems where I have cron. Basically, cron is flaky and ugly and error-prone, with Symfony I get an elegant system, configurable, extensible, with proper error/exception management, control over asynchronous stuff, using the rest of my Symfony app classes, etc. It's just a world above. Thanks for the help!

I updated Symfony Docs with this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/20439
